# Hibernate @Formula annotation causing sql exception errors when hibernate inserts table reference inappropriately

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I'm trying to use a Hibernate @Formula to import some calculated information into one of my Entity classes.  This is the code:

```
@Formula("(select max(site_visits.`date`) from site_visits where site_visits.siteId = id)")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date lastSiteVisit;
```

I've tried the query manually and it works fine.  The problem is that when I request the object, the SQL hibernate generates gets mangled: it insists on inserting its own table reference into the middle of my column reference expressions, so I get the following SQL error:

```
Unknown column 'site_visits.site0_.date' in 'field list'
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Alias

```
@Formula("(select max(sv.date) from site_visits sv where sv.siteId = id)")
```

Also don't use **`** in queries

Comment: I was under the impression that "date" was a reserved SQL keyword and therefore needed to be escaped if used in a field name.  It turns out that this isn't the case, but if I was using a field name that was an SQL keyword, how would I cope with this?

Comment: well using alias is best way I think and if your table name is also sql keyword then use `schema_name.table_name` but if you ask me it is never a good idea to use SQL keyword as a column or table name